# how to rewrite url using htacess

Tags: apache, codeigniter, url, .htaccess

> https://example.com/folder/subfolder/demo1
>   https://example.com/folder/subfolder/demo2
>
> i want to open the above urls as https://example.com/demo1
>   https://example.com/demo2
>
> if i open https://example.com/folder/subfolder/demo1 it should open
>   https://example.com/demo1
>   it should not show **folder/subfolder** in the address bar. it should automatically show and open the desired custom link. it should only rewrite not redirect.
>   please help

Comment: _"if i open `https://example.com/folder/subfolder/demo1` it should open `https://example.com/demo1` it should show `folder/subfolder` in the address"_, this paragraph is confusing

Comment: i apologize for typo. please check it again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to write the rules like this :

```sh
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^folder/subfolder/(.*)$ ./$1 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: can you tell me the exact folder. should i edit .htaccess of https://example.com or should i add .htaccess in https://example/folder or in https://example/folder/subfolder ????

Comment: add it in the root folder (i.e. the `example.com` folder)

Comment: hey can you provide me the above code with force HTTPS too?. please do not edit the previous one provide me a new one please

Comment: Hi @xyz1234, I've added the force https rule

Comment: 10x @hasta-dhana